# Redmine current user information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am working in Redmine 1.4, there are many users in my database. I have a function which needs to get the user who is currently logged. How can I achieve this?

Comment: done it using user_id = session[:user_id]

Answer (score 1):

Not being a ruby expert myself, take a look at how it's done in the source. For example, in [`user_controller.rb`](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/tags/1.4.0/app/controllers/users_controller.rb), the current user is retrieved using **`User.current`**.

`User.current` is defined in [`user.rb`](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/tags/1.4.0/app/models/user.rb), and set in the [`application_controller.rb`](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/tags/1.4.0/app/controllers/application_controller.rb) (of which `user_controller.rb` inherits):

```
User.current = find_current_user
```

`find_current_user` is defined just below that line. Therefore, as long as `application_controller` is executed, you should be able to use `User.current`.

Comment: Using `User.current` is the recommended way to access the current user. By using `session[:user_id]` you are relying on implementation details, which may change in the future.